# Is there any way to start an activity by clicking on anyone of the devices found Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm developing an Android Studio Java app where if users are near each other, then using Bluetooth I can list the devices nearby.

**I wanted to know if there is any way that on clicking on any one of the devices found, I can view that specific users profile, without connecting/paring to them.**

Any insights on this could be really helpful, thanks.

I will be creating an activity where I will be able to turn Bluetooth on/off and all other Bluetooth features that we find on our mobile device also I will be creating the users profile activity and users' data will be stored in firebase database

Comment: What do you mean by "view that specific users profile"?

Comment: users will have their own profile on my app.
so i basically want the users using my app to be able to view each others profiles when they are near each other.

i am realizing now that bluetooth is not going to help me in this situation.

is there any other way?

Comment: And the profile is linked to their Bluetooth address? So that if I'm in range to your Bluetooth I can view your profile?

Comment: yes you got it right

Comment: can we link the profile to the bluetooth address?

Comment: You just need to store the Bluetooth address together with the profile in your database. If you find a Bluetooth Address that you know, show the profile (on selection)

Comment: im pretty new to this stuff , so im finding all possible ways.
my project is due soon, so im finding the best and easiest way to do this.

another way ive come accross is geofire, i still havent yet understood how to work around this

Comment: ohhh kkk, guess i will have to see how to store bluetooth address together with the profile in the database.

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase, but regarding your question: It is your app, you control what it does. Start by listing all Bluetooth devices you find. You don't need to connect to them if you don't want to. You decide what happens if you select one